# --Java-- Server not correctly playing Audio from Client --Real Time Streaming--

Tags: java, sockets, audio, tcp, real-time

I have a client and server application.
The server requests an audio stream and the client handles well.

The client proceeds to setup an AudioFormat(Note: settings are the same on both ends) and TargetDataLine. It Then writes the data to a Socket output stream using a ByteArrayOutput Stream.

The server receives the Data and reads it in a threaded method. During each buffer read it it saves to a AudioInputStream which is passed to a playSound method which is threaded and synchronized to proceed to play the sound.

When i make the playSound method non threaded it works well but slightly glitchy.
Also i know having the play sound non threaded can cause sound frames to jam up
Any help is well appreciated, and any ways I can make this audio stream more efficient and fast is also welcomed.

Client:

private void captureAudio() throws CommandException {

```
    Socket session = new Socket(host_, port_); 
        try {
            final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(
            TargetDataLine.class, format);
            final TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine)
            AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            line.open(format);
            line.start();

            int bufferSize = (int)format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
            byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
            running = true;
                try {         
                    while (running) {

                            int count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                            if (count > 0) {
                               BufferedOutputStream out_ = null;
                               out_ = new BufferedOutputStream(socket_.getOutputStream());
                               out_.write(buffer, 0, count);
                               out_.flush();

                              }    
                    }
                    out_.close();
                    line.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new CommandException("I/O problems: " + e,Command.TRANSFER_ERROR);
                } 
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            throw new CommandException("Line unavailable: " + e,Command.ERROR);
        }
    else {
        throw new CommandException("Unable to Connect to Server",Command.CONNECTION_ERROR);
    }
}

private AudioFormat getFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 16000;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
    int channels = 2;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = true;
    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate,sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
```

}

Server:
        public void readSocket(final Socket socket) {
        new Thread() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputStream input;
            try {
                input = socket.getInputStream();

                final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
                int bufferSize = (int)format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
                byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead;
                while (((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1 ) ) {
                    if (bytesRead > 0) {
                        play(new AudioInputStream(input, format, buffer.length / format.getFrameSize()));
                    }
                }
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }


        }
    }.start();

}


private AudioFormat getFormat() {
  float sampleRate = 16000;
  int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
  int channels = 2;
  boolean signed = true;
  boolean bigEndian = true;
  return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 
    sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
}
```

private synchronized void play(final AudioInputStream ais)  {
        new Thread() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final AudioFormat format = getFormat();
                DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
                SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                line.open(format);
                line.start();

                int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() 
                  * format.getFrameSize();
                byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

                int count;
                while ((count = ais.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                  if (count > 0) {
                    line.write(buffer, 0, count);
                  }
                }
                line.drain();
                line.close();
                ais.close();
            } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
        }
    }.start();
```

}

Comment: do you got any solution, in case of YES, please share with us, thanks